# VideoJS. Error when closing popup in flash mode

Tags: video.js

I have problem with video js.
I am  getting

> ["Video.js: buffered unavailable on Flash playback technology
>   element.", TypeError]   Object # has no method
>   'vjs_getProperty'

when trying to close popup window with video in flash mode.
Someone has solution for this problem ?

I am using 4.0 CDN hosted version of videojs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone needs.

**You you should run myPlayer.dispose() before the modal closes.**